# How do I pass parameter with React Router?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom

When I try passing a parameter using `react-router-dom`, I get a `404 Not Found` error. If I remove the parameter, it works fine. Id like to pass a user name to the page so it can change dynamically.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "../css/App.css"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import WelcomeVisitor from '../pages/WelcomeVisitor'
import ThankYou from '../pages/ThankYou'
import RabbitmqService, { connectRabbit } from '../rabbitmq/RabbitMQService'


function App(){


    connectRabbit()

    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/thankyou" component={ThankYou}/>
            <Route path="/welcome/:user" component={WelcomeVisitor}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );

  }

export default App
```

WelcomeVisitor component:

```
import React from 'react'
import "../css/WelcomeScreen.css"
import Trapezoid from '../components/Trapezoid'
import GuestName from '../components/GuestName'
import Logo from '../components/Logo'

export default function WelcomeVisitor(props){
    return (
        <div className="parentView">
            <Trapezoid />
            <GuestName guestName={props.match.params.user}/>
            <Logo />
        </div>
    )
}
```

GuestName component:

```
import React from 'react'
import '../css/GuestName.css'


export default function GuestName(Guest){
    console.log(Guest.guestName)
    const name = Guest.guestName
    return(
        <div>
            <h1 className="guestName"> {name} </h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('app'));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

For example when I enter `http://localhost:8080/welcome/bob` I get a 404 and it says the request url is `Request URL: http://localhost:8080/welcome/index_bundle.js`.

Comment: so if i understand correctly if you type `/welcome/john`, you the 404 even though you have declared `path="/welcome/:user` in your route?

Comment: Make sure to make `guestName` lowercase like `guestname` when passing the props

Comment: @UdenduAbasili correct it will still get the 404

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to latest react-router,  you no longer need to treat the component inline. You can use:

`<Route path='/foo' >
  <Foo userName='JohnSnow' />
</Route>`

However, for older versions, you can use render props(note render props only has match, location and history. you can pass variables to the component which is a child element)

`<Route path='/foo' render={(renderProps) => <Foo userName={some Username} />} >`

It might have typos, but yiu should get the concept. (typing from Mobile).